# Regex to remove spaces from Key but not Value

Tags: json, regex

I have the following JSON object

```
{
    "Submitter":"Fred",
    "Create Date":"2019-11-05T11:31:58.000+0000",
    "Assigned To":"Some Person",
    "Last Modified By":"Fred@acme.com",
    "A String of Four": "A String with 4 words and 3 spaces",
    "Another Test": "Four Words Appear Here",
}
```

I want to remove all the spaces from the Keys (E.g. "Created Date", and "A String of Four" etc) However I do not want to remove the spaces in the values.

I have tried the following, but this picks up all the spaces except those that follow a quote and a colon (":)

```
(?!")\s(?!")(?!:)
```

I also tried

```
\s(?=\w*\":)
```

but this only picks up the **last space** before a word ending with a quote and a colon (":) and none of the other spaces in the Key.

My next attempt and the one I think I am getting closest with is this:

```
(?<=").*?(?=\w*":)|(?<!":)(?!.*?)(?=\w*)
```

I am testing with https://regex101.com/

Comment: Why would you use `regex` for this task ? a simple `str.remove(' ')` will do the trick.

Comment: @ChihebNexus: Probably the OP wants the regex to operate over the entire JSON string.

Comment: @RobertHarvey humm good point.

Comment: Try `\s(?=[^"]*":\s*")` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/VhXVJb/1)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Very good.  Post that as an answer.  You can shore up the answer with the explanation that is provided from Regex101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably try the following expression as a quick fix granted the JSON you need to fix is in the format you have shown (it might fail to work with other JSONs):

```
\s(?=[^"]*":\s*")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VhXVJb/1)

**Details**

- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?=[^"]*":\s*")` - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current position, requires

  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
  - `":` - `":` string
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `"` - a double quote.

Comment: how to implement this to json object? i am new in this javacript and really appreciate if you give me example.